# Openlayers 4.4.0+ text style not recognizing scalable units (Ems)

Tags: openlayers

We are currently trying to upgrade our app from Openlayers v4.2.0 to v4.4.2 and we are having a problem displaying a text style using the scalable units (Ems) in the font property. Below is the snippet used to create the text style.

```
var fill = new ol.style.Fill({ color: "black" });
var textStyle = new ol.style.Text({
  text: "A",
  font: "normal 1em Lato",
  textBaseline: 'bottom',
  fill: fill
});
```

In [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/jtpetro/pen/ZapGeQ) I have used version 4.3.4 and the text matches the font size specified in the body.

In [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/jtpetro/pen/wPzagO) I have used version 4.4.0 and the text is much smaller. I believe it is using the default `font` property value of `10px sans-serif` as specified in [this](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Text.html) documentation.

Is there something being done incorrectly in my font property value? Or is there another way to achieve scalable units using Openlayers text style and the newer versions? Or is it not recommended to be using scalable fonts in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text rendering system was completely rewritten in v4.4.0, for better performance. The difference you are seeing comes from the fact that text is now pre-rendered to a separate canvas, which does not inherit any css from the DOM. So whatever `font-size` you have in your body (or any css that affects the map container), the `em` of text rendered on the map will always be based on the default `font-size` of the used font.